# Android Studio Compile Error persists

Tags: java, android, build, compilation, transfer

Using android studio

When I try to compile with this in the main activity it gives the error at the end of the post

The code i use:

```
public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
        // do something when the button is clicked
        Button button=(Button) v;
        File from = new File(Environment.getInternalStorage().getAbsolutePath()+"/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db");
        File to = new File(Environment.getExternalStorage().getAbsolutePath()+"/backup/contacts2.db");
        from.renameTo(to);
```

Then I get this error :

```
Error:(25, 42) error: cannot find symbol method getInternalStorage()
Error:(26, 40) error: cannot find symbol method getExternalStorage()
Error:(34, 41) error: cannot find symbol method getExternalStorage()
Error:(35, 39) error: cannot find symbol method getInternalStorage()
Note: C:\Users\Alex\AndroidStudioProjects\QuickTransfer\app\src\main\java\com\am\tpz\quicktransfer\MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Perhaps because the api is [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)

Comment: @epicdig07: don't reuse accounts between co-workers then. Get your own account, and if a question was not as good as it could have been, *update the existing question*.

Answer (score -1):

Ok i found it. That works but you must put the following permissions in the android manifest. and change the

```
getExternalStorage
```

to

```
getExternalStorageDirectory
```

the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```